# The blog created by hexo is invalid on github pages

Tags: github

I encounter a problem, now I use hexo built for a personal blog: https://darr-en1.github.io/

But then the deployment to https://github.com/Darr-en1/Darr-en1.github.io: Out of curiosity, I set the project as private, and then it becomes 404, which cannot be accessed, and then I set it as public, which cannot solve this problem,
Then I delete the project and recreate it then `hexo d`, but still cannot be accessed.

Can you help me?

```
deploy:
  type: git
  repo: https://github.com/Darr-en1/Darr-en1.github.io.git
  branch: master
```

When I opened the developer tool, the error was shown as follows:

> Refused to load the image 'https://darr-en1.github.io/favicon.ico'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "img-src data:".

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Content Security Policy Reference](https://content-security-policy.com/) [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360666/6309) and see, as [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137635/content-security-policy-directive-img-src-data-error#comment85287936_49138057) if you need to use `useHash: true`.

See also if you have a [redirect issue as an SPA (Single page Application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745319/refused-to-load-favicon-ico-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security#comment94343505_53745319)

Finally, as a GitHub Page, make sure to select master as your publishing branch, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42921315/6309).
See "[Configuring a publishing source for GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages)".